# Passing around and evaluating rust closures

Tags: lambda, rust

I'm having difficulty passing around and evaluating lists of closures.  Massively simplified, this program exhibits the same errors as the program I'm trying to write:

```
use std::vec::flat_map;

#[main]
fn main() {
  let list:~[~fn()->~[~str]] = get_list();
  //let res:~[~str] = flat_map(list, |&f|{f()});
  let res:~[~str] = flat_map(list, apply);
  println(res.to_str());
}

fn apply<T>(f:&fn()->T) -> T {
  f()
}

fn get_list() -> ~[~fn()->~[~str]] {
  ~[
    ~||{~[~"foo"]},
    ~||{~[~"bar"]},
    ]
}
```

This is basically trying to to take a list of functions returning lists and transform it into a flat list of results from running the functions.  I get two compiler errors though:

```
temp.rs:7:35: 7:40 error: mismatched types: expected `&fn<no-bounds>(&~fn:Send() -> ~[~str]) -> ~[<V3>]` but found `extern "Rust" fn(&fn<no-bounds>() -> <V4>) -> <V4>` (expected &-ptr but found fn)
temp.rs:7   let res:~[~str] = flat_map(list, apply);
                                             ^~~~~
temp.rs:16:2: 19:5 error: mismatched types: expected `~[~fn:Send() -> ~[~str]]` but found `~[~&fn<no-bounds>() -> ~[~str]]` (expected fn but found ~-ptr)
temp.rs:16   ~[
temp.rs:17     ~||{~[~"foo"]},
temp.rs:18     ~||{~[~"bar"]},
temp.rs:19     ]
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Firstly, neither the function `apply` nor the lambda that I've got commented out allow me to map across the list of functions.  Secondly, in the function `get_list()` I'm unable to generate an acceptable vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems: one is a bug in Rust, the other is actually a problem with your code.

- The bug in Rust is inference with closures is (currently) *horrible*, one has to give them explicit types when one wants anything other than `&fn`. (One filing of this is [#2190](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/2190).)
- The bug in your code is due to the type of [`flat_map`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/vec/fn.flat_map.html)

  ```
  pub fn flat_map<T, U>(v: &[T], f: &fn(t: &T) -> ~[U]) -> ~[U]
  ```

  The point is it passes `&T` to the closure, thus, since we have a `~[~fn() -> ~str]`, the closure receives a `&(~fn() -> ~str)`. To call such a beast, we need to dereference it, which `|&f| f()` does, but in an illegal way. The legal method is `|f| (*f)()`.

  The incorrect method will make `f` have type `~fn() -> ~str` which means that `f` has ownership of the closure (since `~` has a destructor, and so [moves ownership](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/tutorial.html#move-semantics) when passed around), but one cannot take ownership of a value that's contained in a *borrowed* pointer (that would be impolite). The legal one doesn't ever attempt to take ownership, `(*f)()` is (effectively) coercing the `~fn() -> ~str` to `&fn() -> ~str` before it is called. (This is explicit if one uses `apply` correctly too: `list.flat_map(|f| apply(*f)))`.)

```
fn main() {
  let list = get_list();
  let res = list.flat_map(|f| (*f)());
  println(res.to_str());
}

fn get_list() -> ~[~fn() -> ~[~str]] {
    let f1: ~fn() -> ~[~str] = || ~[~"foo"];
    let f2: ~fn() -> ~[~str] = || ~[~"bar"];

    ~[f1, f2]
}
```

(Note I removed the unnecessary type annotations, and used the [`flat_map` method](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/vec/trait.ImmutableVector.html#tymethod.flat_map) rather than the function, since this is the Rust style.)

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful.  You can probably tell I'm still wrapping my head around the type system :).